unexpected troubles converting char array to float
I have a char array and need to convert it to convert it to float.
I have two 16 bit values:
A = 7C37
B = 428B
and they need to be arranged like 42 8B 7C 37 to represent 69.743 in float but I have troubles to get there, I have tried the following:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char pData[8] = {0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7c, 0x37, 0x42, 0x8b};
    float floatValue;
    uint32_t raw;

    raw = ((uint32_t)pData[5]) | (((uint32_t)pData[4])<<8) | (((uint32_t)pData[7])<<16) | (((uint32_t)pData[6])<<24);

    // Copy the bytes in the correct order into the float variable
    memcpy(&floatValue, &raw, sizeof(floatValue));

    // Print the float value
    printf("The float value is: %f\nThe raw value is 0x%x\n", floatValue,raw);

    return 0;
}

but am confused as this unexpectedly produces the following output:
The float value is: -nan
The raw value is 0xff8b7c37

I assume the -nan probably shows because of the 0xff in the left most Byte, it should be set to 0x42, anyone can assist me with this?
UPDATE:
I basically want to implement the Float - Big Endian (ABCD) from https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/ where 428B7C37 produces 69.74261

Without investigating it myself, have you read about endianess lately? Is the data maybe prepared for you to make the endianess correction? Edit: The code and comments don't make sense. You pick ad choose bytes from here and there. Please describe the plan - why you do what you do

What is the practicality of representing a character array as a float? It wouldn't work for character arrays larger than the size of a float type anyways.

On my system 0x428b7c37 is -nan too. What makes you think that is a valid representation of a float ?

Hi all, I've added an UPDATE above

@TedLyngmo I want to create arrange the bytes in the following order: 42 8B 7C 37

You could convert a float to a char array and see what you get.

... 69.743f gives me 6A 7C 8B 42 in reverse order, however one byte is different: 6A instead of 37 (not the 42) presumably due the lack of significance in 69.743.

Once I got to squeeze the chars into a 32bit uint, it's as easy as:
#include <stdio.h>

union FloatIntUnion {
    float f;
    unsigned int i;
};

int main() {
    union FloatIntUnion fiu;
    fiu.i = 0x428B7C37; // Set the integer value
    printf("%f\n", fiu.f); // Interpret the bit pattern as a float and print it
    return 0;
}


unsigned int i; better as uint32_t i; as unsigned may not be 32-bit - which float commonly is. IAC, it needs to match float size.

As @chux-ReinstateMonica says, the union members must have identical sizes. It can be checked with the following static assertion: _Static_assert(sizeof(((union FloatIntUnion *)0)->f)==sizeof(((union FloatIntUnion *)0)->i), "size mismatch");

@nielsen Perhaps a more direct test: _Static_assert(sizeof fiu.i == sizeof fiu.f, "size mismatch"); inside main()?

Consider first converting the float to its bytes.
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  float floatValue = 69.743f;
  for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof floatValue; i++) {
    const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *) &floatValue;
    printf(" %02X", p[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

For me, code prints " 6A 7C 8B 42".
Byte order, byte size and other details are implementation dependent.
Now reverse the process.
Know that 69.743 cannot be exactly represented as a float.  Instead a nearby value is formed.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  float floatValue;

  unsigned char pData1[sizeof floatValue] = { 0x37, 0x7C, 0x8B, 0x42 };
  memcpy(&floatValue, pData1, sizeof floatValue);
  printf("%.9g\n", floatValue);

  unsigned char pData2[sizeof floatValue] = { 0x6A, 0x7C, 0x8B, 0x42 };
  memcpy(&floatValue, pData2, sizeof floatValue);
  printf("%.9g\n", floatValue);
}

Output
69.7426071
69.7429962

